# OCaml: finally clause related issues

Tags: ocaml, finally

```
type 'a result =
  Success of 'a
| Failed of exn

let finally f x cleanup =
  let result =
    try Success (f x) with
      exn -> Failed exn
  in
  cleanup ();
  match result with
    Success y -> y
  | Failed exn -> raise exn
```

There are several places I do not understand:

1. the syntax of finally
2. exn is a type, how can we use it in a pattern matching? Failed exn?
3. Success (f x) matched with exn?
4. relationship between cleanup and f x.

Comment: The etiquette here is not to end your questions with “thank you”, and OCaml is capitalized as “OCaml”: http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/name.en.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is supposed that use will use finally something like that:

   ```
   let h = open_db () in
   let f db = ... return someting from db in
   let res = finally f h (fun () -> close_db h) in
   ```
2. exn is a type but name spaces for types and values are almost not mixing in OCaml. So, when you write `Failed exn` `exn` is name binding
3. `Success (f x)` is not returned if exception raises during  evaluation `f x`.
4. `x` is resource which you should free in finally branch, `f` does some work with created `x`